# How was this 2048 bit number factored so fast?

Tags: rsa, attack, factoring

I'm working on a [CTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capture_the_flag#Computer_security). The challenge is to get the contents of an encrypted message given the ciphertext and the 2048-bit RSA public key. I did finally get the flag after a few hours, but I'm still not sure why the first step worked.

The first step -- factor *n* into its two prime factors is from what I can tell, not supposed to be feasible, but it was done in about 1 second on [this website](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM). Why was it so easy?

> n=25224507456159163156575877796028456473662369736904878100933060887887244216120260281695328861739056294270643097794317308976759958367437549244808863772906680939521070489582647498438244915199705468395817575606597814019562913707562306397168764567686787293933393417031620511244511892437239390863502308155450078419924080263102978663897532365363981719762081750552627197211945486141442274528746322354522651902908903406950060094343722668988129318030729213169059762443357730983377434699924583492845212206319390320703622866477008711013644010886555820367734996512061432529391693421190426715896428082690439073605633199475981032823
> e=65537

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That number was so quick to factor because its factors are extremely close together, i.e., it factors as $\left(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor + 70\right)\left(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor - 68\right)$.

Some algorithms, like [Fermat's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method), which work best the closer together the factors are, will find this factorization instantly.

Comment: ohh, I see thank you. I thought maybe it was something like n was 2^2048-1, or maybe there was some type of factoring rainbow table, but that makes more sense

Comment: @rainbowkitty227 Rainbow tables aren't relevant to integer factorization.

Comment: Ryan Sheasby wrote two good articles describing what rainbow tables actually are (and why they're usually useless these days): https://rsheasby.medium.com/rainbow-tables-probably-arent-what-you-think-30f8a61ba6a5 and https://rsheasby.medium.com/rainbow-tables-probably-arent-what-you-think-part-2-probability-efficiency-and-chain-9e2fb5e8cdc9

Comment: In particular, the site uses a quadratic sieve which is like an extension to Fermat's method.

Comment: IOW, the puzzle designers picked this specific number, just like textbook authors pick nice round numbers.