# When is a large semiprime possible to factor?

Tags: factoring

Under which conditions is a large semiprime possible to factor? In particular, is the following 400-digit semiprime actually trivial to factor into primes?

6962155154859963260211100482357357666900094513013513488352858667799199787495340476167566639530574848375895722792291996203873323650274512138128403360943634134259376986501375967452208380337012919869885380406071772232795575963202558402893589313281327208179913789760736615950818685956393838601277519011418885197723428318400763080858914698836058070301404903262955501113318317950597435778777212408626799143

Comment: My goal of the edit was to ensure the nice answer does not go to waste.

Comment: Thank you, @kodlu!

Comment: 400 digits is too high for a CFT to just factor [Prime factorization (102 digits)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/89560/18298). May be you should try the Fermat factoring method.

Comment: Duplicate of [How was this 2048 bit number factored so fast?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/91404/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka: The integer in [How was this 2048 bit number factored so fast?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/91404/18298) was factored on the first step of Fermat's factoring. This one resists at least a few thousands. I used that [simple Mathematica code](https://pastebin.com/ukxGkpkM).

Comment: More of a duplicate of this one: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67384/factoring-rsa-weak-modulus/67458

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this 400 digit semiprime does have a large weakness that
enables it to be factored in hours.

I have factored this number, so you could be kind and tell me
where this CTF is so that I can get credit.(Said half joking)

Neither Fermat's nor ECM nor SNFS is going to help you in any
reasonable amount of time.

The p factor has 41606 in the 15-19th upper digits and q has
89827 in the 15-19th upper digits.

---

Update <sub><sup>(moved here by moderator)</sup></sub>

*Perhaps this class of methods?*  No
*Or/and using a multiplier?*  No

Spoiler alert - the factors are given below.
.
.
.
.

```
n= 6962155154859963260211100482357357666900094513013513488352858667799199787495340476167566639530574848375895722792291996203873323650274512138128403360943634134259376986501375967452208380337012919869885380406071772232795575963202558402893589313281327208179913789760736615950818685956393838601277519011418885197723428318400763080858914698836058070301404903262955501113318317950597435778777212408626799143
                                                                                          p= 1055314811678641606424788110765439117222699930257095408671007391029759113842109970448108699505224742945927781061767905202515184760446787611555372203775837301834490832771874109424228620164137709228509254318229660698954763303449460372503950485172061048411036447824270015301213488707
                                                                                          q= 6597230587321689827469274987496974524162638657985346941557775305494810601668451103917887716603988821282535336087463657549
```

Comment: Indeed, straight Fermat won't cut it. I also tried a fair amount of Pollard's p-1 (ecm -pm1 4e9) and William's p+1 (ecm -pp1 2e9), to no avail, and some ECM. If ECM does not help, then Pollard's Rho won't. Perhaps [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/198606) class of methods? Or/and [using a multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method#Multiplier_improvement)? One way to convince people one has factored $n=pq$, without revealing the factorization, is to publish $t=2^{n^{-1}\bmod((p-1)(q-1))}\bmod n$. Then anyone can check that $t^n\bmod n=2$.

Comment: Ah, got it. Should have looked at $n$ in hex or binary. Nice.

Comment: Nice, @MostlyResults! Did you use the algorithm due to Coppersmith?  ("Small Solutions to Polynomial Equations, and Low Exponent RSA Vulnerabilities", J. Cryptology (1997) 10: 233–260)

Comment: @Sam Blake: I guess MostlyResults guessed from the hex form of $n$ that $n=(r\,2^i+s)(t\,2^j+u)$ with small $(r,s,t,u)$.

Answer (score 6):

"Trivial" is almost certainly the wrong word for this. A better question is if it is reasonable to efficiently factor.
First, it is worth mentioning that your semi-prime is 400 *decimal* digits. Multiplying this by $\log_2(10)$, we see that it is $\approx 1300$ bits long.
This is vastly larger than the largest claimed factoring (of semiprimes) record of [829 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization_records).
So the answer is "no", unless your semiprime has special structure that makes it "weak".

What special structure might semi-primes have?
Let $N = p_1p_2$ be the factorization.
There are a few candidates, which work if

1. One of the $p_i$ is *small* (say at most $\approx 60$ bits), then the [elliptic curve method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization) is reasonable to run.
2. One of the $p_i$ is such that $p_i+1$ is *smooth*, e.g. all prime factors of $p_i+1$ are bounded by some reasonably small number $B$. Then [William's $p+1$ algorithm is reasonable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williams%27s_p_%2B_1_algorithm).
3. One of the $p_i$ is such that $p_i-1$ is *powersmooth*, e.g. all prime *power* factors of $p_i-1$ are bounded by some reasonably small number $B$. Then [Pollard's $p-1$ algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm) is reasonable.

There may be a few other "special structures" that I am missing (I seem to remember one if $p_1\approx p_2$, but can't recall the name now). Your only real chance of factoring the number is for it to be improperly generated though, which all of the above would be examples of, so unless you have a specific reason to think they are improperly generated (say this is a CTF challenge) I wouldn't bother trying to break it.

If you have a reason to think this should be improperly generated, implementations of these exist.
For example, [Sage](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/explicit_methods_in_number_theory/integer_factorization.html) has an implementation of the ECM (via GMP-ECM).
In the [GMP-ECM](http://ecm.gforge.inria.fr/) page itself, I also see references to $p-1$ and $p+1$, but I don't know if sage directly tries these as well (as they are only really useful if you suspect the semiprimes have been improperly generated).

But without hitting one of these cases of "weak semiprimes" (which are exceedingly unlikely to occur if the semiprime is properly generated --- so unless you have reason to think this is a *weak* RSA semiprime it is probably not even worth checking).

Comment: For whatever it's worth, Magma online calculator could not factor this. You are allowed 120 CPU seconds but I don't know what processor they use but their approach is described here: https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/182 calculator: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

Comment: Thank you, @Mark. I'm presently trying to factor p+1, p-1, q+1, q-1 to see if these primes satisfy any of these conditions.

Comment: Actually, Elliptic Curve Method is fairly effective at finding primes smaller than 128 bits, and has a decent probability at finding primes somewhat larger than that...

Comment: And, for $p_1 \approx p_2$, Fermat's method finds the factors quickly...

Answer (score 2):

The technique used was to reduce N to a special form that was easily factored.

Displayed N in binary and noticed hundreds of 0's in between 4 numbers.

This was reduced to the following:

N = a*2^1228+b*2^875+c*2^353+d

where
a= 1506291488774150974626762365373
b= 322571915263178581
c= 576377099039115423
d= 123431

Treating this as a polynomial in x, with x=2:

N = a*x^1228+b*x^875+c*x^353+d

This factors very quickly to:

(359561509069941*x^353+77)*(4189245652768553*x^875 + 1603)

Comment: To answer your question (that was edited out). I put the example together myself as a test for some integer factorisation experiments I have been doing. Here's a slightly more challenging one:
 7215955072690155355400859323297730634528493510676300043022948136348249037517276095868127042993906604904230826475281383188764473510881994780947137238252071087749294743150564851420395422525735221770067605216401023

Comment: Many years ago I encountered a 124 bit key (yes, many years ago) of the form 2^123 + a x 2^60 + b for small an and b. Factored it by hand. The primes were apparently taken from a table in TAOCP.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment @Sam Blake asked a follow up question about an integer to factor:

7215955072690155355400859323297730634528493510676300043022948136348249037517276095868127042993906604904230826475281383188764473510881994780947137238252071087749294743150564851420395422525735221770067605216401023

The question is this 2nd semiprime actually trivial to factor into primes?

This semiprime is not weak because it does not give up its' special form very easily.

It is weak for an adversary with nation state capability because it is only 701 bits.
A 2048 bit or higher modulus with equal bitlength p and q are recommended.

Also it doesn't appear to have weakness using Fermat's, p-1, it's ratio is not near a small
fraction, ECM is not helpful.

This integer does not appear to match a special form that is easy to factor. Even though
once the special form is recognized the number can be factored with much less effort,
detecting which special form can be very time consuming as there are many forms.

What hints are you willing to give? That this is a semiprime? That the factors
are of unequal length? That the factors are polynomials with terms:
a0 x 2^(k0) + a1 x 2^(k1) + a2 x 2^(k2)...

Comment: Hey @MostlyResults, it is a semiprime with a 293-bit prime factor.

Comment: Here's an algorithm that factors the examples quickly: https://github.com/stblake/factor_rational_base/

Comment: @SamBlake This was an interesting problem at first.  
Wrote a Pari/GP program to find the special form of the semiprime  
72159...01023   
  
It only took 23 seconds on one core to find the special form:  
 round((49/9)^167)+2857  
  
The two factors followed:  
80213...08313 and 89959...71671

Comment: Nice work @MostlyResults! Now it would be nice if there was a clever way to (simultaneously) eliminate many candidate rational bases. And/or some sort of gradient descent-based way to converge on 49/9, perhaps through analysis of the base a/b representation of N? If I had a clever way to do it I wouldn't be posting here though...